# Randomly distributed images shader

Tags: procedural, shader-nodes

I know how to distribute planes with image textures on a plane. But I want to know if it'd be possible to scatter images procedurally with shader nodes.

Comment: This might be something that is easier done with pure python using something like the [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

Answer (score 0):

This is a paid solution so might not be ideal but I have an addon available from BlenderMarket which does exactly that.

[UV Scatter](https://blendermarket.com/products/uv-scatter) scatters textures around on surface geometry by manipulating UV coordinates. The nodes can scatter, move, rotate, scale, and animate textures as well as add effects like blur, drop shadow, and parallax. It can also create layers of images and effects and stack them on top of each other.

I hope you find it useful.